# Converting float to int in C++

Tags: c++, math, integer

I am talking about converting floats that already store integer values (like **10.0**)
I need to do this because I want to create a simple function that reverses a given integer, and it uses a line of code that looks something like this: `ans += x % (int)pow(10, i);` (the % operator needs both arguments to be integer, and pow returns a double)

C++ is not very happy doing this conversion properly. For `pow(10, 4)`, I get a value of **9999**, which is very irritating. Why this error occurs is obvious, 10^4 must have been stored as **9999.999999...** or something like that. I could possibly fix this error by using the `lround()` function, but that would be a less than optimal solution because what if I overlook a similar error like this?

Is there a way to do mathematics in C++ without worrying about such trivialties? If not, what language should I choose to do computation like this? I have briefly used the bigInt library in python. Any suggestions regarding which language and library to use to tackle this issue would be very helpful.

Comment: `lround` seems to be exactly what you need - why do you say that it's "less than optimal"?

Comment: "10^4 must have been stored as 9999.999999"
Read up the IEEE754 standard, it covers how float numbers are stored to memory

Comment: Have a read of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I don't want to deal with implementation complexity that C++ poses. When the code didn't work, I assumed that there was a problem with the logic, and wasted quite some time figuring what went wrong. My purpose is purely academic, so C++ offers no real advantage to me in terms of speed. I just wanted to hear from people what libraries/language/techniques they use when they want to focus completely on algorithms and not worry about if the language would offer hurdles.

Comment: When it comes to floating-point precision, you'd get similar issues in most other languages.

Comment: @AayushMahajan Binary floating point number numbers can not accurately represent Decimal floating point numbers in the vast majority of cases.  So you have 3 choices: (1) abandon floating point and use multi-precision integer arithmetic, (2) learn what binary floating point is and determinate if it meets your needs or (3) use a 3rd party multi-precision (big-number) library,

Comment: So you want a language that lets you focus completely on the problem with no overhead from learning the language or working around its quirks. That is inherently impossible.

Comment: If you apply this operation very often, then it would be better to pre-compute an (long) integer array `powof10` so that `powof10[k]` is exactly `10^k` by just iterating `powof10[k+1]=10*powof10[k] `.

Comment: *"What if I overlook a similar error like this?"* How could you overlook it? You had to insert an explicit cast to `int`, so just train yourself to round instead of cast. It won't be any slower. That simple-looking cast is not free.

Comment: *"Is there a way to do mathematics in C++ without worrying about such trivialities?"* Choosing the right data types for your application is **not** a triviality; in fact, it's probably the *most* important decision you make as a programmer. If you need decimal values to be exact (infinitely precise), floating point numbers are the wrong choice for that. If they don't need to be *exact*, but merely *close enough*, then `lround` seems like the way to do that.

Comment: (Although beware of large numbers, too -- `pow(3, 34)` will never round correctly because `double` can't represent 16677181699666569 to within an accuracy of 1.0.)

Answer (score 2):

In other languages you have types for doing accurate math operations like in C# you have the [decimal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/decimal) and in Java the [BigDecimal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) type for example. So that problems like this:

```
printf (" %.20f \n", 3.6);
--> 3.60000000000000008882
```

or

```
0.1 + 0.2
--> 0.30000000000000004
```

does not happen.

In C++ you can use for example: [The GNU Multiple Precision arithmetic library](http://gmplib.org/) or [Boost.Multiprecision](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/index.html) or [DecimalForCPP (header only)](https://github.com/vpiotr/decimal_for_cpp). Surely there are more libraries available.

If you use such types, remember that they are slower than the inaccurate floating point types. But if you work with money for example, it's a must!